# Center columns in TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, tablelayoutpanel

I want to create this TableLayoutPanel (C# in WinForms - programatically created at runtime!)

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
|   01.01.2010 01:00   |   01.01.2010 01:00   |   01.01.2010 01:00    |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|   Some text       |  More            | And         | Final text     |
|   (Multilined)    |  multilined      | more text   | Multiple lines,|
|                   |  text            |             | too            |
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But currently it lookes more like this

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
| 01.01.2010 01:00 | 01.01.2010 01:00 | 01.01.2010 01:00              |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| Some text    | More       | And       | Final text                  |
| (Multilined) | multilined | more text | Multiple lines,             |
|              | text       |           | too                         |
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I achieve the layout above - meaning, the columns' width is adjusted to fit the whole table equally - but if a column needs more space, it can resize itself to the preferred size?

Comment: Doesn't setting AutoSize property for columns to true help?

Comment: I'm not sure, how should I set that property and to what? I create all tables programatically at runtime... See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529098/multiple-tablelayoutpanels-for-complex-table for the creation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the column Size Type to Percent instead of Absolute.  Select the panel, click the little arrow glyph in the upper right corner, Edit Rows and Columns.

Comment: I create the table at runtime, so I can't use the WinForm Designer. See -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529098/multiple-tablelayoutpanels-for-complex-table

Comment: Well, start another project, drop a TLP on the form and format it.  Look at the generated code in the Designer.cs file and reproduce that in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is old, but it doesn't seam to be properly answered. Look at the `ColumnStyles` property, just shooting from the hip it would look something like this:

```
TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles(0) = New ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100/TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Count)
```